# Apache's Alias directive is not working as expected

Tags: php, apache2, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2, mod-alias

I am trying to integrate my portal with my website.

My website :

```
http://example.com
```

and My portal :

```
http://portal.com
```

Now I want to see my portal from :

```
http://example.com/portal
```

Part of my core apache config file (sites-enabled/website):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example/WebSite2.0/WebContent
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    <Directory /home/example/WebSite2.0/WebContent>
            Options  +IncludesNOEXEC
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            XBitHack On
            AddType text/html .html
            AddHandler server-parsed .html   
    </Directory>

    Alias /portal /home/example/portal/CodeIgniter_2.1.0
    <Directory /home/example/portal/CodeIgniter_2.1.0>
            DirectoryIndex "index.php"
            allow from all
            Options +Indexes
            #Options  FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            Order allow,deny

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /portal
            #RewriteRule ^test\.html$ test.php 

            RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

            RewriteCond $1 ^(css|images|js)
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you see my portal functions on top of CodeIgniter; Hence -

```
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Part of my core apache config file (sites-enabled/portal) :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName portal.com
    ServerAlias www.portal.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example/portal/CodeIgniter_2.1.0
    DirectoryIndex "index.php"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "ssl/portal.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "ssl/portal.com.key"
    <Directory /home/example/portal/CodeIgniter_2.1.0>
            Options  FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Header unset Server
            ServerSignature Off
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the real problem is when I open http://example.com/portal the browser is looking for the images in the `DocumentRoot` and not in `Alias`.

e.g. for image from portal,

```
<img src="/images/example.png" style="margin-left:30px;height:50px;">
```

apache error log says -

```
File does not exist: /home/example/WebSite2.0/WebContent/images/example.png
```

I would hate to make changes to my code. I just want to get this thing working from the apache config file itself. Please help me do this.

Comment: Can you paste the configure of `portal.com` here?

Comment: done. added it to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteBase /portal` require that the url should begin with `/portal`. So:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
```

will not be hit.

```
<img src="/images/example.png" style="margin-left:30px;height:50px;">
```

will try to search file from `DocumentRoot`.

### update1

For there is `RewriteBase /portal`, `example.com/portal/images` will hit the Rewrite rule, but `example.com/images` will not, so:

```
 <img src="/images/example.png" style="margin-left:30px;height:50px;">
```

should be:

```
 <img src="/portal/images/example.png" style="margin-left:30px;height:50px;">
```

### update2

It is the answer given by @Hussain Tamboli himself, with:

```
RewriteRule /(images|js|css)/(.+)\.(.+)$ /portal/$1/$2.$3 [PT].
```

`/images/Invoice.png` will rewrite to `/portal/images/Invoice.png`

Comment: what is the full path of `example.png`?

Comment: Here - `/home/example/portal/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/images/example.png`

Comment: You can use `http://portal.com/images/example.png` to access this image, now you want to use `http://example.com/portal/images/example.png` to access this file, right?

Comment: Replying to your answer. You said "will not hit.". But the rewrite condition below that works fine. To verify it, I did `RewriteCond $1 ^(css|images|js) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ css` and you see http://example.com/portal/images or js redirects me to http://example.com/portal/css

Comment: Yes, `example.com/portal/images` will hit, but `example.com/images` will not.

Comment: I think. I am gonna have to do it without `RewriteBase`; Write a separate rule to match /images/anything and then replace it by /portal/images/anything. Can you help me write those rules?

Comment: Do you mean map `example.com/images/anything` to `/home/example/portal/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/images/anything` ?

Comment: No. Like in the update 1, you have mentioned. just add `/portal` to `/images/example.png`.

Comment: Your current config can map `example.com/portal/images/example.png` to `/home/example/portal/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/images/example.png`. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes. but when I hit example.com/portal, CI's index.php redirects me to  example.portal/users/login?redirectURL=/? where the images don't appear

Comment: `example.com/portal` map to `/home/example/portal/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/index.php`, I think this file will check login, if your did not sign in, will redirect to `example.portal/users/login`

Comment: This is what I am talking about - `RewriteRule /(images|js|css)/(.+)\.(.+)$ /portal/$1/$2.$3 [PT]`. To verify this, I checked the rewrite log. It says `applying pattern '/(images|js|css)/(.+)\.(.+)$' to uri '/images/Invoice.png'` and `rewrite '/images/Invoice.png' -> '/portal/images/Invoice.png'`. You can add this to the answer

Comment: Yes, that is right. In this rewriterule, `<img src="/images/example.png" style="margin-left:30px;height:50px;">` will output the image you want.